# python standard lib equivalent to dateutil.parser.parse

Tags: python, datetime, standard-library, python-dateutil

I'm parsing datetimestamps using python dateutil, but would like to avoid the extra dependency. So Is there a way to do the equivalent with the standard python library:

```
dateutil.parser.parse("2012-12-12T12:00")
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Write your own using `strptime` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your date strings are all in the same format, you could use [strptime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) like this:

```
In [31]: import datetime as DT

In [32]: DT.datetime.strptime("2012-12-12T12:00", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
Out[32]: datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 12, 12, 0)
```